# Downvote for a questions based on immense research?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

[Spring Boot really worth ? with the mammoth sized jar creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103831/spring-boot-really-worth-with-the-mammoth-sized-jar-creation#)

I guess, I had met actually this criteria,though of late to find it out so. So "Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs."

Am not sure why some one gave here negative points stating "Not enough research" done on the subject !! 2 weeks of deep exploration with hell lot of experiments came to this conclusion. I have raised around 4/5 pertaining questions here related to the topic.

May I know the rationale behind the decision -some one please.

Comment: Only the voter can tell you why they chose to vote. No one else can. Mindreading is not a meta feature.

Comment: But after cursory reading your question, it seems very unclear, to say the least. Then again, I don't know much about the implicated technology.

Comment: The title is opinion based ("is X really worth it?"), and I have some difficulty parsing your question at the end.

Comment: Any takers? Any takers for what? Our opinions about Spring boot, we don't do opinions here.

Comment: `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful` <-- Note the "unclear" part.  After reading the question a couple of times, I'm still not quite sure what you're asking (unclear).  I *think* what you're asking is how big the jars would be?  IF that is your question, it'd be impossible for anyone to answer given we don't have all of your source code.  Maybe someone here can help you clarify the question a bit.

Comment: **Immense research** you mean to looked up the size of the jar after it was build? I don't see much references to that immense research, or it must be that one question you linked to?

Comment: Since it's your first time in meta, do not fret down-votes on your question here. They do not affect your reputation in main. And at least you've a lot of food for thought about your original question.

Comment: And hopefully our meta-friends will give you a chance to try to fix your question before down-voting you to oblivion in main...

Comment: *sigh* If I had a dollar for every OP claiming to have done immense amounts of research, hours of Googling, months of experimenting ... and nothing in their question showing any trace of said work.

Comment: @Justastudent You will be richer than Bill Gates ;)

Comment: You!! have!!! some !!!!! large !!!!!!! number of `!!!!!` in the posts. Please !!!!!!! use them less!!!!!!!!!! Would you????????????

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov while true, that's just nitpicking. An excess of exclamation/interrogation points is easily edited out.

Comment: @yivi indeed it can be edited out. But it also easily can change perception of the question from "meh, nothing special, no votes" to "I dislike this shouting, here is my vote". I don't see any good reason why OP would intentionally make post less likable - maybe they just don't see it as a problem that requires someone to spend time to make post better.

Comment: Using multiple punctuation marks is a side-effect of doing immense research.

Comment: @Martin any stats about that?!?!?!?!?!?!!!!?!?!!!?!?!?!??!?!?!?! (Filled with punctuation, so it shows you did your research, of course!!!!1!1!1!one!1)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're asking an opinion here.  You're asking us what we think about handling the JARs that are produced from it, and you're looking for feedback on that aspect.

Inevitably, that'll generate answers which reply, "I handle my JARs in X fashion."  X will be different for every answerer.

I disagree with the angle of "not enough research", and no one has commented to that effect, either.  This looks like a cut-and-dry "opinion-based" question.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know about the other downvoters, but this is my analyis:

- Your Grammar is poor.  It's poor enough that I had a bit of trouble reading through the question.  This will cause people to downvote.
- Your question is too broad.  It sounds like you've encountered multiple issues with your approach, and you're asking "is it worth it?"  Try to boil it down to 1 question.
- The phrase: "Any takers ?" is poison.  It makes it sound like you have a more substantial task for us to perform, instead of a simple question.  It'll cause the faster readers to assume that your question is a requirements dump.

Comment: Also too many exclamation points ! Almost every sentence ends with one ! Even though the questions in the post don't, why ? It is not necessary !

Comment: I take some umbrage with grammar as a quantifier (even though you may be correct).  There are problems with the question which go beyond its grammar, punctuation, and sentence flow; at a minimum, the grammatical problems of that can be edited.  But even if you *did* edit it, what you're left with is a question soliciting opinions.

Comment: @Makoto Grammatical problems *that don't impact your ability to understand the question* can just be edited, and don't need to affect a vote.  Grammar problems *significant enough to impair your ability to understand what's being asked* both can't be fixed, and are a major factor to consider when voting on a post.  This questions falls into the latter case for me at least.

Answer (score 9):

This is your title:

> Spring Boot really worth ? with the mammoth sized jar creation

That would be the opening of a blog post and I expect to find a rant, I hope about Spring Boot but it could be about mammoth's as well.

What follows is an attempt to explain what kind of POC you build. 5 classes and you are forced to use a container.

Those are great facts !! (always use double bang, for more impact)

Near the end there is this sentence:

> Question is Spring Boot while ease out developers life, from perspective of build,package,deploy it ends up pretty tough muddy task of handling mammoth sized jars ?

I'm not a native speaker but I'll try to make sense of it by leaving some words out that I think are not needed:

Attempt 1:

*Question: Is Spring Boot it ends up pretty tough muddy task of handling mammoth sized jars ?*

Attempt 2:

*Question: Is Spring Boot from perspective of build, package, deploy of handling mammoth sized jars ?*

Attempt 3:

*Question is Spring Boot it ends up pretty tough muddy task of handling mammoth sized jars ?*

Still not sure. I think you're looking for ways to reduce the size of your jars but it might be something else.

> Any takers ?

No thanks, I'll cast a down vote instead.

---

How about asking your question something like this:

---

**How can I reduce the large size of JARS in Spring Boot /Camel Rest application**

My target is to convert an old OSGI based Camel application to a cloud based service app for which I am experimenting with Spring Boot with Camel Rest application.

I've build a simple POC app having just 4/5 java classes handling Camel+Rest application and I notice the resulting JARS are 26 MB. Based on [Multiple camel context not accepted in Spring Boot Came single configl xml model ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101459/multiple-camel-context-not-accepted-in-spring-boot-came-single-configl-xml-model) I can't host all my 10 apps on the same JVM.

The size of these JARS is bothering me for reasons of [I have no idea, memory? Size on disk? delivery payload? class loader hogging?] . What are my options to reduce the size and/or overcome the issues caused by the size?

---

*disclaimer: I have no idea what I'm talking about*

Comment: Man, you are mean. Please take pity on the people that may be drinking hot beverages while they read your answer. My keyboard is wet. Thank you.

Comment: "Is Spring Boot it ends [..]" still looks weird. I would start the question with "Does" :P.

Comment: @Tom I thought it was meant for comedic effect. **But snorting tea is not funny**.

Comment: @yivi Might be the case, I don't know :D. (for both cases)